# Apply reg import in MDT Task Sequence

Tags: deployment, wds, mdt

I have a couple Registry files that I'm trying to import through MDT.
I created a folder called Reg inside the scripts folder on the MDT server and put the files in there. I added individual command line task sequences with the line `reg import %scriptRoot%/reg/MyRegFile.reg`.
It is under the State Restore task sequence.

The registry entry is not added when I search inside Registry. If I manually double click the reg file on the target machine it imports fine.
Not sure which windows/logs/mdt file to look in to see why it failed.

Comment: Is the reg import running in Windows PE Mode?

Comment: It is also recommended to not put your system configurations in the script root, all system modifications should be in the apps system as a packaged app, this will prevent overwrite during updates and potential permission misconfigurations that would let an attacker gain remote control of your distribution share server and managed systems.

Comment: @ElliotHuffman Not sure,  since the import is not not running at all.

Comment: @ElliotHuffman are there steps to create a packaged app?

Comment: When you say the import isn't working, what does the powershell error say?

Comment: @ElliotHuffman the registry was not applied. When viewing the MDT script logs, I don't see it ever applied.

Comment: I don't see it in the MDT-Ps.log file

Comment: Join me in this chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/148024/mdt-troubleshooting-rick?tab=general

Comment: I created a PowerShell script to import the registry keys and that seemed to work. I did see the log with 0 return with the name of the task schedule entry and it did apply.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your question with that, I will upvote it.